# Annualized Turnover Report

Tags: sql, sql-server

What can be made better? How ugly is my code? If it's terrible, where can I improve?

```
DECLARE @startDate char(8);
DECLARE @endDate char(8);
DECLARE @termStart char(12);
DECLARE @Facility nvarchar(255);

-- ************************** IMPORTANT **********************
-- SET THE START AND END DATES TO PULL DATA FOR THE DATE RANGE
-- ***********************************************************
SET @startDate =    '20150601';
SET @endDate =      '20150630'; 
--SET @startDate =  '20150701';
--SET @endDate =        '20150731'; 
SET @termStart =    LEFT(@endDate, 4) + '0101';
SET @Facility=      '918' 

select @startDate, @endDate

create table #tmp_month_turnover
(
    Id int,
    EmpStatus nvarchar(255),
    [Monthly TO] DECIMAL(18,2)
)

  /* ABD JUNE TERMS */
  SELECT   distinct a.personidno as 'PersonId', --COUNT(distinct a.PersonIdNo) 
    CASE    WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Full Time' THEN 'RFT'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'PRN' THEN 'PRN'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Part Time' THEN 'RPT'
            ELSE a.EmploymentStatus
    END as 'EmpStatus'
  into #tmp_month_terms_list
  FROM [WfcSuite].[dbo].[_KIC_EmployeeInfo] a inner join tEMPLOYMENT_STATUS b on a.personidno = b.PersonIdNo
  where 
  a.EmploymentStatus IN ('Regular Full Time', 'Regular Part Time', 'PRN') 
  AND b.OrgCodeIdNo = @Facility and
  (b.[TerminationDate] >= @startDate +  ' 00:00:00' and b.[TerminationDate] <= @endDate +  ' 23:59:59') 

   select '' as 'Id', EmpStatus,  COUNT(*) as 'Monthly Terms' 
   into #tmp_month_terms 
   from #tmp_month_terms_list group by EmpStatus

   insert into #tmp_month_terms
   select top 1 '', 'PRN', '0' from #tmp_month_terms_list where NOT EXISTS (Select * from #tmp_month_terms_list where EmpStatus = 'PRN') 
   insert into #tmp_month_terms
   select top 1 '', 'RFT', '0' from #tmp_month_terms_list where NOT EXISTS (Select * from #tmp_month_terms_list where EmpStatus = 'RFT') 
   insert into #tmp_month_terms
   select top 1 '', 'RPT', '0' from #tmp_month_terms_list where NOT EXISTS (Select * from #tmp_month_terms_list where EmpStatus = 'RPT') 

   insert into #tmp_month_terms
   select '' as Id, 
   'SubTotal' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RFT' ))

    insert into #tmp_month_terms
   select '' as Id,
   'All' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RFT' )
   +
    (select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'PRN' ))

   update #tmp_month_terms
   set Id = 1
   where EmpStatus = 'RPT'

   update #tmp_month_terms
   set Id = 2
   where EmpStatus = 'RFT'

   update #tmp_month_terms
   set Id = 3
   where EmpStatus = 'SubTotal'

   update #tmp_month_terms
   set Id = 4
   where EmpStatus = 'PRN'

   update #tmp_month_terms
   set Id = 5
   where EmpStatus = 'All'

  /* ABD JUNE HC */
  SELECT  distinct a.personidno as 'PersonId', --COUNT(distinct a.PersonIdNo) 
    CASE    WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Full Time' THEN 'RFT'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'PRN' THEN 'PRN'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Part Time' THEN 'RPT'
            ELSE a.EmploymentStatus
    END as 'EmpStatus'
    into #tmp_month_headcount_list
  FROM [WfcSuite].[dbo].[_KIC_EmployeeInfo] a inner join tEMPLOYMENT_STATUS b on a.personidno = b.PersonIdNo
  where 
  a.EmploymentStatus IN ('Regular Full Time', 'Regular Part Time', 'PRN') 
  and  b.OrgCodeIdNo = @Facility 
  and b.EmploymentStatus <> 5 and a.employeestatus <> 'Terminated'

  select '' as Id, EmpStatus, COUNT(*) 'Monthly HC' into #tmp_month_headcount from #tmp_month_headcount_list group by EmpStatus

    insert into #tmp_month_headcount
   select '' as Id, 'SubTotal' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RFT' ))

    insert into #tmp_month_headcount
   select '' as Id, 'All' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RFT' )
   +
    (select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'PRN' ))

    update #tmp_month_headcount
   set Id = 1
   where EmpStatus = 'RPT'

   update #tmp_month_headcount
   set Id = 2
   where EmpStatus = 'RFT'

   update #tmp_month_headcount
   set Id = 3
   where EmpStatus = 'SubTotal'

   update #tmp_month_headcount
   set Id = 4
   where EmpStatus = 'PRN'

   update #tmp_month_headcount
   set Id = 5
   where EmpStatus = 'All'

    /* ABD JUNE TO */
    insert into #tmp_month_turnover
     select '2' as Id, 'RFT' as 'EmpStatus',
            CAST(
                (( cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RFT') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                / 
                CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RFT') AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
                * 100)
            AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Monthly TO'


    insert into #tmp_month_turnover
     select '1' as Id,'RPT' as 'EmpStatus',
            CAST(
                ((cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RPT') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                / 
                CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RPT') AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
                * 100)
            AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Monthly TO'

    insert into #tmp_month_turnover
     select '5' as Id, 'PRN' as 'EmpStatus',
            CAST(
                ((cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'PRN') AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                / 
                CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'PRN') AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
                * 100)
            AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Monthly TO'

            --select * from #tmp_month_turnover

    /* ABD JUNE Turnover Subtotal */
    insert into #tmp_month_turnover 
    select '3' as Id, 'Subtotal' as 'EmpStatus',
            CAST(
                    (   
                        (
                            (select cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RFT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                                +
                                cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RPT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                            )
                            / 
                            (   CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RFT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                                +
                                CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RPT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                            )
                        )
                * 100)
AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Monthly TO'

    /* ABD JUNE Turnover All */
    insert into #tmp_month_turnover 
    select '4' as Id, 'All' as 'EmpStatus',
            CAST(
                (((select cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RFT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                +
                 cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'RPT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                +
                 cast((select [Monthly Terms] from #tmp_month_terms where EmpStatus = 'PRN') AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
                / 
                ( CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RFT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                +
                 CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'RPT') AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                +
                 CAST((select [Monthly HC] from #tmp_month_headcount where EmpStatus = 'PRN') AS DECIMAL(18,2))))
                * 100)
            AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Monthly TO'

    --select * from #tmp_month_turnover 

    /* ABD YTD TERMS */
  SELECT   distinct a.personidno as 'PersonId', --COUNT(distinct a.PersonIdNo) 
    CASE    WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Full Time' THEN 'RFT'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'PRN' THEN 'PRN'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Part Time' THEN 'RPT'
            ELSE a.EmploymentStatus
    END as 'EmpStatus'
  into #tmp_ytd_terms
  FROM [WfcSuite].[dbo].[_KIC_EmployeeInfo] a inner join tEMPLOYMENT_STATUS b on a.personidno = b.PersonIdNo
  where 
  b.OrgCodeIdNo = @Facility 
  AND  a.EmploymentStatus IN ('Regular Full Time', 'Regular Part Time', 'PRN') 
  AND (b.[TerminationDate] >= @termStart + ' 00:00:00' and b.[TerminationDate] <= @endDate + ' 23:59:59') 

   select '' as Id, EmpStatus, COUNT(*) as 'YTDTerms' 
   into #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
   from #tmp_ytd_terms group by EmpStatus
   --select  COUNT(*) as 'cnt' 
   --into #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
   --from #tmp_ytd_terms 

    insert into #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   select '' as Id, 'SubTotal' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [YTDTerms] from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt where EmpStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [YTDTerms] from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt where EmpStatus = 'RFT' ))

    insert into #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   select '' as Id, 'All' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [YTDTerms] from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt where EmpStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [YTDTerms] from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt where EmpStatus = 'RFT' )
   +
    (select [YTDTerms] from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt where EmpStatus = 'PRN' ))

    update #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   set Id = 1
   where EmpStatus = 'RPT'

   update #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   set Id = 2
   where EmpStatus = 'RFT'

   update #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   set Id = 3
   where EmpStatus = 'SubTotal'

   update #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   set Id = 4
   where EmpStatus = 'PRN'

   update #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
   set Id = 5
   where EmpStatus = 'All'

    /* ABD YTD HC AVG */
    ;WITH
CTE_EmployedPeople
-- this is how many people were employed on each day in the given period
AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM
        ,[_KIC_EmployeeInfo].EmploymentStatus
        ,COUNT(distinct [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].PersonIdNo) AS People
    FROM
        dbo.Calendar
        CROSS JOIN [_KIC_EmployeeInfo]
        INNER JOIN tEMPLOYMENT_STATUS b on [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].personidno = b.PersonIdNo
    WHERE
        b.OrgCodeIdNo = @Facility
        AND [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].EmploymentStatus IN ('Regular Full Time', 'Regular Part Time', 'PRN') 
        --and [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].EmployeeStatus = 'Active'
        AND (dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM >= @termStart)
        AND (dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM <= @endDate)
        AND (dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM >= [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].LastHireDate)
        AND (dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM <= [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].TerminationDate 
             OR [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].TerminationDate IS NULL)
    GROUP BY dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM, [_KIC_EmployeeInfo].EmploymentStatus
    --ORDER BY CALENDARDTM
)
,CTE_Daily
-- if it is possible that nobody was employed on a certain day
-- left join previous results to the Calendar table again to get 0 for such days
AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM
        ,CTE_EmployedPeople.EmploymentStatus
        ,ISNULL(CTE_EmployedPeople.People, 0) AS People
    FROM
        dbo.Calendar
        LEFT JOIN CTE_EmployedPeople ON dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM = CTE_EmployedPeople.CALENDARDTM
    WHERE
        (dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM >= @termStart)
        AND (dbo.Calendar.CALENDARDTM <= @endDate)
)
-- simple average of daily numbers
SELECT '' as Id,
    CASE    WHEN EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Full Time' THEN 'RFT'
            WHEN EmploymentStatus = 'PRN' THEN 'PRN'
            WHEN EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Part Time' THEN 'RPT'
            ELSE EmploymentStatus
    END as 'EmploymentStatus'
    , AVG(People) AS 'YTD Avg HC'
into #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
FROM CTE_Daily
GROUP BY EmploymentStatus;

insert into #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   select '' as Id, 'SubTotal' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [YTD Avg HC] from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [YTD Avg HC] from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT' ))

    insert into #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   select '' as Id, 'All' as EmpStatus, 
   ((select [YTD Avg HC] from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT' )
   +
    (select [YTD Avg HC] from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT' )
   +
    (select [YTD Avg HC] from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg where EmploymentStatus = 'PRN' ))

     update #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   set Id = 1
   where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT'

   update #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   set Id = 2
   where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT'

   update #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   set Id = 3
   where EmploymentStatus = 'SubTotal'

   update #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   set Id = 4
   where EmploymentStatus = 'PRN'

   update #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
   set Id = 5
   where EmploymentStatus = 'All'

 /* ABD YTD TO RATIO */
 select 
    '' as Id,
    EmploymentStatus,
    cast(
    cast((a.[YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    /
    cast((b.YTDTerms) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'YTD TO Ratio'
    into #tmp_ytd_turnover
    from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg a, #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt b where a.employmentstatus = b.EmpStatus

    update #tmp_ytd_turnover
   set Id = 1
   where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT'

   update #tmp_ytd_turnover
   set Id = 2
   where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT'

   update #tmp_ytd_turnover
   set Id = 3
   where EmploymentStatus = 'SubTotal'

   update #tmp_ytd_turnover
   set Id = 4
   where EmploymentStatus = 'PRN'

   update #tmp_ytd_turnover
   set Id = 5
   where EmploymentStatus = 'All'

 --/* ABD YTD TO RATIO Subtotal */  
 --insert into #tmp_ytd_turnover
 --select
 --'SubTotal' as 'Employment Status',
    --cast(
    --((select
    --cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    --where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT')
    --+
    --(select
    --cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    --where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT'))
    --/
    --((select
    --cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    --where EmpStatus = 'RPT')
    --+
    --(select
    --cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    --where EmpStatus = 'RFT'))
    --AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'YTD TO Ratio'


 --/* ABD YTD TO RATIO All */   
 --insert into #tmp_ytd_turnover
 --select
 --'All' as 'Employment Status',
    --cast(
    --((select
    --cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    --where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT')
    --+
    --(select
    --cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    --where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT')
    --+
    --(select
    --cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    --where EmploymentStatus = 'PRN'))
    --/
    --((select
    --cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    --where EmpStatus = 'RPT')
    --+
    --(select
    --cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    --where EmpStatus = 'RFT')
    --+
    --(select
    --cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    --from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    --where EmpStatus = 'PRN'))
    --AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'YTD TO Ratio'

 /* ABD ANNUALIZED TO */
 select 
    '3' as Id,
    'Subtotal' as 'EmploymentStatus',
    cast(
    (((select
    cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    where EmploymentStatus = 'RPT')
    +
    (select
    cast(([YTD Avg HC]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg 
    where EmploymentStatus = 'RFT'))
    /
    ((select
    cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    where EmpStatus = 'RPT')
    +
    (select
    cast(([YTDTerms]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
    from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt 
    where EmpStatus = 'RFT'))

    / 6) * 12 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as 'Annualized TO'
    into #tmp_annualized_to

insert into #tmp_annualized_to
select '1' as Id, 'RPT', 0.00

insert into #tmp_annualized_to
select '2' as Id, 'RFT', 0.00

insert into #tmp_annualized_to
select '4' as Id, 'SubTotal', 0.00

insert into #tmp_annualized_to
select '5' as Id, 'All', 0.00

    --select * from #tmp_month_headcount a   order by Id asc
    --select * from #tmp_month_terms b  order by Id asc 
    --select * from #tmp_month_turnover c   order by EmpStatus desc
    --select * from #tmp_ytd_hc_avg d  order by EmploymentStatus desc
    --select * from #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt e   order by EmpStatus desc
    --select * from #tmp_ytd_turnover f  order by EmploymentStatus desc
    --select * from #tmp_annualized_to h   order by EmploymentStatus desc

    --drop table #tmp_month_terms 
    --drop table #tmp_month_terms_list
    --drop table #tmp_month_headcount 
    --drop table #tmp_month_headcount_list
    --drop table #tmp_month_turnover
    --drop table #tmp_ytd_terms
    --drop table #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt
    --drop table #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
    --drop table #tmp_ytd_turnover
    --drop table #tmp_annualized_to

    select a.*, 
    b.[Monthly Terms],
    c.[Monthly TO],
    d.[YTD Avg HC],
    e.YTDTerms,
    f.[YTD TO Ratio],
    g.[Annualized TO]
    from #tmp_month_headcount a 
    join #tmp_month_terms b on a.Id=b.Id 
    join #tmp_month_turnover c on b.Id=c.Id  
    join #tmp_ytd_hc_avg d on c.Id=d.Id 
    join #tmp_ytd_terms_cnt e on d.Id=e.Id  
    join #tmp_ytd_turnover f on e.Id=f.Id  
    join #tmp_annualized_to g on f.Id=g.Id 
      order by a.Id asc
```

End results:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the schema on http://sqlfiddle.com?